# Go to a community page without having to login first

Tags: apex, visualforce, community

When I go to this url:

https://rockpool.force.com/forgotpasswordConfirm

I'm redirected to the login page. I want this page to be public and not need to login first to access it. I didn't code anything to make it redirect but it does so anyway. I have enabled a visualforce page called ForgotPassowrdConfirm on the site visualforce pages. Anyone know why it might be redirecting?

Comment: Did you set it up under `Sites` already? Your post doesn't make clear what steps you've already taken beyond just developing the `Visualforce Page`.

Comment: I created the community and I enabled the ForgotPasswordConfirm page for site visualforce page. And I gave the community user profile access to the visualforce page. That's all that is needed right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did everything correctly, and even checked to make sure the API version was up to date. Nothing worked. I created a new page with the exact same markup and it works just fine. Must be a Salesforce glitch.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to expose a `Visualforce Page` to unauthenticated access, you must set up a [`Site`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Sites) (emphasis mine):

> Force.com Sites lets you create public web applications and web sites that run natively on Force.com - under your own domain. Force.com Sites lets you easily extend the reach of your existing applications to new, external audiences, and **your site visitors don't need to authenticate to view your pages**. In fact, if you're already using Visualforce to create your user interfaces, it's a simple matter of bundling them into a Force.com Site to create a public web application.

Comment: I said previously that I already did that. I went to the community clicked go to force.com, then added the page to the enable visualforce page for site related list.